# Dynamic view compilation and rendering express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Is there a way to compile and render a .jade view on the fly eg. if it was stored in a db or would it have to be written to the file system first or is it possible to hook into the view system to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I know is that Express/Jade allow template modification without restarting the server.

Also, instead of trying to hook Express to render a string, why don't you simply [use jade directly](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade#readme) and send it to the client ? Few untested, pourly ordered lines of code to help :

```
var jade = require('jade');    

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    var fn = jade.compile('string of jade');
    res.send(fn(locals));
});
```